# Auto-Resize Text over Image HTML

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I want write 2 numbers over an image , Like that:

[image: like this]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/e7c2527827.png))</sub>

So, i've done this effect with this  CSS code:

```
 #container {
  position: relative;

}
#image {
    height: 22%;
  position: relative;
   display: inline-block; 
  margin-top:3px;
  vertical-align: bottom;


}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:nexa;
  left: 150px;
  top: -50px;
}
#textdx {
  position: absolute;
  color: #787d83;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:nexa;
  float:right;
  width:50%;
  right: 150px;
  top: -50px;
}
```

and this is my HTML code:

```
<div id='container'>
<img id='image' src='imgA.png'></img>
<p id='text'>5</p>
<p id='textdx'>5</p>
</div>

<div id='container'>
<img id='image' src='imgB.png'></img>
<p id='text'>6</p>
<p id='textdx'>6</p>
</div>
```

The problem is when i resize my browser window or i open the page on a computer with different sizes of screen and the results are:

[image: issue]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/e7c2602c15.png))</sub>

How could i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

in order to solve this problem you have to use percentages values of positions instead of fixed pixel values. also you have to resize your text font size according to the window's width with JavaScript (I choose the window as a reference in my example).
here is my example code (I have downloaded and used your first image) :

html:

```
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="inner-container">
        <img class='image' src='img/imgA.png'></img>
        <p class='num text'>5</p>
        <p class='num textdx'>5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
   <style>
    .container {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
    }

    .image {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .text {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0px;
      top: 7%;
      left: 23%;
    }

    .textdx {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0px;
      top: 39%;
      left: 76%;
    }

    .num {
      font-size: 70px;
    }
  </style>
```

js:

```
    <script>
      var windowInitWidth = window.innerWidth;
      var nums = document.getElementsByClassName('num');

      // get the value of num font-size
      var numFontSize = window.getComputedStyle(nums[0]).getPropertyValue("font-size");
      numFontSize = Number(numFontSize.replace("px", ""));

      console.log(numFontSize);

      // update the text font-size when resizing the window
      window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        for( var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
          nums[i].style.fontSize = (window.innerWidth / windowInitWidth * numFontSize) + 'px';
          console.log(nums[i].style.fontSize)
        }
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: You are the best:)

Comment: you are welcome Bro. you may need some customization but in general this is the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because in the #text class you set the left to 150px which means it counts from the left 150px and shows the white text, while in the #textdx you set the right to 150px which means it counts from the right 150px and shows the white text. So, in order to solve the problem, just use the same property in both classes (right or left), like in the code below:

```
#text {
  ...
  left: 150px;
  ...
}

#textdx {
  ...
  left: 250px;
  ...
}
```

Please let me know if it helped you, or you expected something else.